# How to rename CJK file from PHP script

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, file, chinese-locale

In PHP 5.5 installed on Windows, I have trouble in renaming file into CJK character. For example,

I tried to use rename() function:

```
<?php
    rename('old_file.mp4', '我的文件.mp4');
?>
```

But it didn't work without any error or warning.  My system locale is Chinese for non-Unicode characters.

Also, I have trouble in uploading a file with Chinese filename to media in Wordpress 4.7.

Thank you for your kind answers.